Simple ergodic convergence proof for iid
This is just a simple question from a problem sheet. Consider a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables $Y_0,Y_1,\dots$. Let $f$ be a function such that $\mathbb{E}|f(Y_0)|^2 < +\infty$, show that
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}f(Y_j)-\mathbb{E}f(Y_0)\right|^2 = 0.
$$
I work through the problem using the following approach: let $g(Y_j) = f(Y_j)-\mathbb{E}f(Y_0)$ then for fixed $N$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}f(Y_j)-\mathbb{E}f(Y_0)\right|^2 &= \mathbb{E}\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}g(Y_j)\right|^2 \\ 
&=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\mathbb{E}g(Y_j)g(Y_k) \\
&=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\mathbb{E}\left|g(Y_k)\right|^2\delta_{jk} \\
&=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\mathbb{E}\left|g(Y_k)\right|^2.
\end{align}
At this point I'm not sure if I am missing a trick with an inequality or something, or if the question needs an additional assumption with $\mathbb{E}f(Y_0) = 0$. Obviously, you are meant to use  $\mathbb{E}|f(Y_0)|^2 < +\infty$, so that that error is proportional to $\frac{1}{N}$. I have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left|g(Y_k)\right|^2 &= \mathbb{E}|f(Y_j)|^2 - 2\mathbb{E}f(Y_j)\mathbb{E}f(Y_0)   +(\mathbb{E}f(Y_0))^2 \\
&= \mathbb{E}|f(Y_0)|^2 - (\mathbb{E}f(Y_0))^2 
\end{align}
as they are iid. If I assume $\mathbb{E}f(Y_0) = 0$, then this all works or do I have to use $\mathbb{E}f(Y_0)$ is finite by Jensen's inequality and then use some other inequality trick?

The function $f$ needs to be Borel measurable. The result can fail otherwise.

Note that $(g(Y_j))$ is also i.i.d. so $\frac 1 {N^{2}}  \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N-1}E|g(Y_j)|^{2}=\frac {(N-1)} {N^{2}}Eg(Y_0)^{2} \to 0$.

Thanks, the sums were corrected to start from $0$ to make it neater. Just needed $\mathbb{E}\left|g(Y_k)\right| < +\infty$
